# Game textures are low resolution after exporting

Tags: game-engine, export, image

When I test-run my game in blender, the images look smooth. Everything looks great! When I export the game to a folder, and run it on the desktop, the images have rough edges and look very low-res. Very disappointing! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please remove all but one simple model and texture from the scene then upload it here.  If you are not sure how to pack a texture then you can just upload it separately.  Here is the address for a site that hosts temporary files so they can be linked.  http://www.pasteall.org/

Comment: puedes subir tu blend en el almacenamiento de blender stack exchange [Upload File](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)